# SAPUI5 - Routing Issue when an async function exists

Tags: javascript, html, controller, sapui5, async.js

I have an SAPUI5 Fiori web application written in JavaScript. The application contains multiple views and I have a NavBar to navigate between the views.
The views are loaded via routing mechanism into the NavContainer element (see: [Nested Navigation in SAPUI5](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/HRSJ44)).

My Problem: When I start the application in Google Chrome, everything works fine. When I start the application in **IE11** or **Edge** the routing does not work. There are no error messages, but the views wont change when i want to navigate.

Now I have startet to analyse the code and found out that, when I have any **async** function in my controller and when I use **await**, then the routing does not work. When i remove all async functions and the await from my controller, then the routing works fine.

I have already tried to remove "use strict" from my controller and I also loaded the polyfill file in my index.html, but it doesn't solve my problem neither.

Does anyone know how i could solve this problem? Because I need the async function calls in my controller.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

My controller code looks like this:

**ProductSelection.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/model/Filter",
    "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator",
    "sap/ui/model/resource/ResourceModel"
], function (Controller, JSONModel, Filter, FilterOperator) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("CS_MOE.Demo.controller.ProductSelection", {

        onInit: function () {

            this.getView().addEventDelegate({
                onBeforeShow: this.onBeforeShow
            }, this);
        },

        onBeforeShow: function (e) {

        },

        getProducts: async function (criteria) {
            var showMore = this.lastMatnr !== "";
            this.setTableProductBusy(true, showMore);

            var oProductFilter = new Filter("Suche", FilterOperator.Contains, criteria);
            var oIndexFilter = new Filter("Last_Matnr", FilterOperator.EQ, this.lastMatnr);
            var oFilters = [oProductFilter, oIndexFilter];
            var result = await this.execRequest(oFilters, "/ARTICLESSet");
        },

        //function to trigger GET-Request for given filters and "target"-EntitySet - promise is used to fulfill the async/await functions
        execRequest: async function (oFilters, entitySet) {

            var oArtikelODataService = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("productService");
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                oArtikelODataService.read(entitySet, {
                    filters: oFilters,
                    async: true,
                    success: function (response) {
                        var oResponse = response.results;
                        resolve(oResponse);
                    },
                    error: function (oError) {
                        console.log(oError);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a time **before** async/await and it was also possible to do async stuff.

Instead of `await this.execRequest(oFilters, "/ARTICLESSet")` you can do `this.execRequest(oFilters, "/ARTICLESSet").then(...)`.

Or simply do `return this.execRequest(oFilters, "/ARTICLESSet")` and later when you call `getProducts` you can do `this.getProducts(sCriteria).then(...)`;

If you really want to use async/await you have to set up Babel which will transpile your code so it works in IE11 when deployed.